# MS SQL Server paging with total rows returned

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I'm trying to get an idea as the fastest way to do server paging using SQL SERVER 2012 with large data-sets whilst returning the EXACT total records.

THAT IS THE EXACT QUESTION

I say this because the more I research this the more people seem to go off on tangents  sort of missing the question itself. I know all about estimating total records, Indexing and hardware updates for performance but that is not what I'm asking.

Currently I'm working with the 'OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY' and I use currently the 'COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows' in my query to attempt to use one query rather than two.

I have had to slightly doctor my query's to accommodate 'COUNT(*) OVER()' when they are DISTINCT in nature.

What are people experiences with this or do you use a different method all together.

It would also be interesting to know whats best to add to the example to test the actual times it takes without any caching compiling etc etc. I have had a small play with this but no matter which way I try I very rarely get the same results for the same query twice.
I'm guessing this is because of other things the OS is doing, hard drive speeds and caching.

NOTE: I have now added some timing and on my tests it does seem that the second query take nearly twice as long as the first.

EXAMPLE:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT 
  SET @RowCount = 0 

DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
( 
  Value1 INT, Value2 INT, Value3 INT
)

-- The above table contains no relevant data and no indexes etc on purpose 
-- as that's not really the point

SET NOCOUNT ON

WHILE @RowCount < 200000 
BEGIN 
  INSERT 
    INTO @TestTable 
      ( Value1, Value2, Value3) 
    VALUES 
      (
       ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10,
       ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000,
       8
      )
    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1 
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF

-- The following WONT work for DISTINCT Because the COUNT(*) OVER() is 
-- calculated first. 
--
-- SELECT DISTINCT Value1, Value2, Value3, COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows 
-- FROM @TestTable 

CHECKPOINT; 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME 

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

-- So we have the following using one query
--
SELECT Value1, 
       Value2, 
       Value3, 
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Value1, Value2, Value3
    FROM @TestTable
    -- INNER JOIN ...
    -- WHERE      ...
) AS foo
ORDER BY Value1
OFFSET (200) ROWS FETCH NEXT (100) ROWS ONLY;

SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()   
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in microseconds] 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

-- And this using TWO querys
--
-- Query ONE
SELECT DISTINCT Value1, Value2, Value3
FROM @TestTable
    -- INNER JOIN ...
    -- WHERE      ...
ORDER BY Value1
OFFSET (200) ROWS FETCH NEXT (100) ROWS ONLY;

--Query TWO
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRows FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Value1, Value2, Value3 
FROM (TestTable) AS Foo

SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()   
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in microseconds] 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

Comment: With the fastest server? Buy more memory? Without completely specifying the environment, database schema, ..., it is impossible to provide you with _the fastest way_. Using triggers to maintain the count(s) would provide the fastest answer(s), but at the expense of slower writes.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument it a simple I7 with 8 Gb of ram and 1 standard ASA disk. The schema is as the example shows. With the acceptation of maybe memory I cannot see the relevance of hardware because different queries run at there same relative speeds if they are on the same hardware. i.e. They will all run faster on faster hardware and all run slower on slower hardware.

Comment: Parallelism, or a lack thereof, can make the choice of hardware significant.

Comment: I hate to go off topic as both are great solutions and OFFSETFETCH is exactly designed for this type of thing.  But take a look at putting DISTINCT in the COUNT.  COUNT(DISTINCT Something) is perfectly valid and *may* result in a slight performance increase.  You'll have to test though.

Comment: Where in the above example would you be using  COUNT(DISTINCT Something) COUNT(DISTINCT Value1) has no relevance and COUNT (DISTINCT Value1, Value2) isn't valid syntax.

Comment: HABO: This is not what the question is about and is not really relevant. Putting 100 Gb of ram makes the hardware significant but it isn't connected to what i have asked.